# A state being updated even if I don't call setstate React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

(React 16.8.6)
I have the problem that when a variable change, it automatically changes also the state even if I don't call any setState. In the handleInputChange when I assign the value, it automatically updates the states clientsData and editedClientsData . I would like to update only editedClientsData.

Here is the code:

1 - set the state (fired on a button click):

```
getClients(calls) {
axios.all(calls)
    .then(responseArr => {
        let cleanedDate = []
        responseArr.map(el => {
            cleanedDate.push(el.data.data)
        })
        this.setState({
            clientsData: cleanedDate,
            editedClientsData: cleanedDate,
            loading: false
        })
        this.loadDataChart()
    });
}
```

2 - load the inputs fields

```
render(){
    return (...
        this.state.editedClientsData.map(this.renderInput)
    ...)
}

renderInput = (client, i) => {
    const { activeYear } = this.state
    return (<tr key={client.id}>
        <td>{client.name}</td>
        <td><Input
            type="number"
            name={client.id}
            id="exampleNumber"
            placeholder="number placeholder"
            value={client.chartData[activeYear].r}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        /></td>
        <td>{client.chartData[activeYear].x}</td>
        <td>{client.chartData[activeYear].y}</td>
    </tr>
    )
}

handleInputChange(event) {
    let inputs = this.state.editedClientsData.slice();
    const { activeYear } = this.state
    for (let i in inputs) {
        if (inputs[i].id == event.target.name) {
            inputs[i].chartData[activeYear]['r'] = parseFloat(event.target.value)
            console.log(inputs)
            // this.setState({ editedClientsData: inputs })
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to assign a fixed number
I tried to save as const {clientsData} = this.state , updating editedClientsData and the this.setState({clientsData})

All of these tests failed. Hope in your helps, thank you!

Comment: Your `for .. in` loop doesn't make sense, are you trying to modify each value in the array?

Comment: Actually this was the last test.. the first version was without the loop and only 
`let { editedClientsData } = this.state`

`const { clientsData, activeYear } = this.state`

`editedClientsData[index].chartData[activeYear][data] = parseFloat(event.target.value)`
But also this code failed.. I had the same wrong result.

Comment: Yes, because if you use index then you're trying to update all the items in array. So how do you know which item needs to be edited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `getClients` function, you are assigning the same array `cleanedDate` to both the props (`clientsData` and `editedClientsData`) of the state.

Both the properties are **pointing** to the same array. So edit will be reflected to both the properties. Now, assuming that the array contains objects, so copying the array using `slice` will also not work, because both the different arrays are containing the references to the same data. Consider the example below:

```
var a = [{prop: 1}];
var b = a.slice();
var c = a.slice();
console.log(c == b); // false
b[0].prop = 2;
console.log(b[0].prop); // 2
console.log(c[0].prop); // also 2, because slice does shallow copy.
```

In this case you need to deeply copy the data, so no reference is duplicated. You can use Lodash utility for this or create your own utility for the same.

Comment: Thank you Salim! Your answer solved my problem. 
The final solution was this one, using Lodash

`getClients(calls) {
  axios.all(calls)
   .then(responseArr => {
    let cleanedDate = []
    responseArr.map(el => {
     cleanedDate.push(el.data.data)
    })
    this.setState({
     clientsData: cleanedDate,
     editedClientsData: _.cloneDeep(cleanedDate),
     loading: false
    })
    this.loadDataChart()
   });
 }`